# What should be the name of a Java source that contains more than one class?

Tags: java

If there is more than one class in one Java source file then what will be the file name of the .java file?

Comment: it's considered rude to press on early replies. Your time is **not** more valuable than ours.

Comment: And it's not as if we read the questions and leave them for later.

Comment: I guess you wouldn't ask this if you ever tried to rename your file.

Answer (score 11):

there can only be one **public** top level class in a java file.  The name of the public class must match that of the file name.  Other than this, there can be as many non public (default/package access) classes as you like.

None of this is part of any java specification, it is just convention but a very convenient one.  This 'convention' also includes such things as java and class files being found in directory structures matching the package name of the class.  Check out [the java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) on this.

Comment: just a small correction. There can only be one **outer public** class. You can still have public inner/static classes :)

Answer (score 4):

Only one class can be public in the same file and the public class is the file name...