# When java class X required to be placed into a file named X.java?

Tags: java, class

Guys, I've come across such legal behaviour:

**File B.java:**

```
final class C {}
final class D {}
```

**File A.java:**

```
class B {}
public class A {}
```

**Questions:**

1. When class X is required to be placed into its own X.java file? Does class visibility/final matter here?
2. Is there any official spec on this class/java relation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The de-facto standard in most implementations is that a source file can only contain one top-level `public` type definition. The name of the source file must be the name of that type.

A source file can contain nested types, but by definition they're not a top-level `public` type.

This is recommended in, but not required by, the Java Language Specification.

> #### [JLS 7.6 Top Level Type Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.6)
>
> When packages are stored in a file system, the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as `.java` or `.jav`) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared `public` (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>
> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a compiler for the Java programming language or an implementation of the Java virtual machine to find a named `class` within a package; for example, the source code for a `public` type `wet.sprocket.Toad` would be found in a file `Toad.java` in the directory `wet/sprocket`, and the corresponding object code would be found in the file `Toad.class` in the same directory.

Note that `final` has nothing to do with accessibility, so it's not a relevant issue in this matter.

#### Related questions

- [What should be the name of a Java source that contains more than one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084187/what-should-be-the-name-of-a-java-source-that-contains-more-than-one-class)

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Packages/Managing Source and Class Files](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)
- [Joseph D. Darcy's blog - Nested, Inner, Member, and Top-Level Classes](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top)

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A public class ClassName must be in a file called ClassName.java.

Non-public classes have no such restriction.

A consequence of this is that a Java source file can have only one public class but as many non-public classes as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can have only one top-level `public` class or interface in a source file, and the source file must have the same name as that class or interface.

This is not something that's in the Java language specification; this is an implementation-specific thing of Sun's (now Oracle's) implementation of the Java compiler. (Other implementations of the Java compiler might not require this).

Comment: It is implementation-specific, but JLS does have a few things to say: implementations "may" choose to do this when packages are hosted in file systems, but in fact "must not" do this if they're stored in a database. So it's "in" the JLS (putting aside the issue of whether such non-mandatory non-specification belongs in there in the first place).

Comment: Ok... strange that the JLS has the "must not" requirement when stored in a database. What's the reason for that requirement?

Comment: I don't know why the JLS has the "must not" requirement when stored in a database.  But when packages are hosted in a database, what is a "source file"?

Answer (score 1):

The Sun/Oracle compiler allows at most one public top-level class per file, in which case the file name must be the class name.

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#26783) does not mandate this behaviour, but explicitly allows it:

> When packages are stored in a file
>   system (§7.2.1), the host system may
>   choose to enforce the restriction that
>   it is a compile-time error if a type
>   is not found in a file under a name
>   composed of the type name plus an
>   extension (such as .java or .jav) if
>   either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in
>     other compilation units of the package
>     in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore
>     is potentially accessible from code in
>     other packages).
>
> This restriction implies that there
>   must be at most one such type per
>   compilation unit. This restriction
>   makes it easy for a compiler for the
>   Java programming language or an
>   implementation of the Java virtual
>   machine to find a named class within a
>   package;